# Does stationary reflection imply Mahloness?

Tags: lo.logic, set-theory, forcing, large-cardinals

Suppose $\kappa$ is strongly inaccessible and every stationary subset of $\kappa$ reflects.  Must $\kappa$ be Mahlo?

Remarks:

1. It is possible for every stationary subset of $\kappa$ to reflect, but $\kappa$ is only weakly inaccessible (and not strongly inaccessible).
2. If $V=L$ then the answer is "yes", and in fact $\kappa$ must be weakly compact.

Comment: In the case of Remark 1, is $\kappa$ at least weakly Mahlo?

Comment: In the model I know of, yes.

Comment: Do you know what happens if you simply use the Mahlo-killing forcing? (Conditions are closed bounded sets containing no regular cardinal.) This forcing is very nice, and has $\delta$-closed dense subsets for every $\delta<\kappa$; so it adds no bounded sets. If you have stationary reflection in the ground model, is this preserved to the forcing extension $V[C]$?

Comment: Joel, I suspect something like thus might work, but only if you do some sort of Prikry preparation.  So that $\kappa $ is singular on the $ j $ side of the forcing, where $ j $ is a generic lifting of a ground model elementary embedding. But even then it's not clear.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Not necessarily.  Here's a counterexample, but I'm sure it is a ridiculous overkill in consistency strength:

Suppose $\kappa$ is the least inaccessible limit of supercompact cardinals.  Then $\kappa$ is not Mahlo.  If $S \subseteq \kappa$ is stationary, then there is a stationary $T \subseteq S$ such that $T$ concentrates on some cofinality $\theta < \kappa$.  Taking a supercompact $\delta \in (\theta,\kappa)$ gives the reflection of $T$ by the usual argument.

Comment: That's fine.  I didn't care about the consistency strength.

Comment: The model in Shelah's paper "Reflecting stationary sets and successors of singular cardinals" has the property that stationary reflection holds for ALL inaccessible non-Mahlo cardinals (and such cardinals exist there).